# How do I display an array where each object in array is a new <td> in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array which contains multiple objects like this:

```
const locations = [
  {
     information: ["Data Analyst", "Uruguay", "Montevideo", "$30,000"],
  },
  {
     information: ["CTO", "UK", "Manchester", "$75,000"],
  }
];
```

And I want to display each array in a new table row containing a `<td>` with each string.

Currently I have done this:

```
<tr>
   {locations.map((location) => <td>{location.information}</td>)};
</tr>
```

Which returns each piece of information on a `<td>`

This is how the data looks at the minute:
[image]

And how it's meant to look
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the code from,

```
<tr>
   {locations.map((location) => <td>{location.information}</td>)};
</tr>
```

To:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" className="component_useRefBox">
  <tbody>
    {locations.map((location, i) => {
      return (
        <tr key={i}>
          {location.information.map((data, j) => {
            return <td key={j}> {data} </td>;
          })}
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To display two records row by row, you need to move `{locations.map((location) .... )}` above `<tr> ... </tr>` tag, because while using `map` method only each row will get iterated and you will get two separate rows..

```
{locations.map((location, i) => {
          return (
            <tr>
                ....
            </tr>
 )})}
```

As `location.information` is of array data, you cannot assign it directly.

You need to iterate using map and display each data like,

```
{location.information.map((data) => {
   return <td> {data} </td>;
})}
```

[image: Edit React Functional Component (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use `Array.map()` like:

```
// To create tha table body by iterating data array
{
    locations.map((location, locationIndex) => 
        <tr key={locationIndex}>
            <td>{location.information[0]}</td>
            <td>{location.information[1]}</td>
            <td>{location.information[2]}</td>
            <td>{location.information[3]}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}

// In case you don't want to harcode the array index
{
    locations.map((location, locationIndex) => 
        <tr key={locationIndex}>
            location.information.map((loc, locIndex) => 
                <td key={locIndex}>{loc}</td>
            )
        </tr>
    )
}
```